# RecyclerView Item contents are not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-recyclerview, apk

Using RecyclerView to show data from JSON, each and every Recycler Item contains an Image, few TextViews

But whenever I run my app, I am getting RecyclerView List but not getting contents and image in it.

What could be the reasons ?

**proguard-rules.pro:**

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit.http.** <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keepattributes Signature
```

Comment: did you check the list adapter contains data or not?

Comment: yes it contains data

Comment: can you post your adapter ?

Comment: I'm sure it's not related to your proguard or signing. Check constructor of adapter ( show Toast ) and see does data come to your adapter.

Comment: apply rules for picasso, support library and other libraries you have used in proguard

Comment: @Sun: Working on Emulator but not on device. Seems strange. Try cleanning project and run again

Comment: include Application class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Proguard is messing with your POJO. It gets obfuscated and thus doesn't work anymore. That's why it also happened just after you enabled minify for debug builds.

You should keep all POJOs and their members, because they are used by reflection. From what I see from your code, you at least need to add

```
-keep class **.CountryPojo { *; }
```

But since this might not be all, you should keep all classes and members of the package you use for the POJO

```
-keep class pkg.of.the.pojos.** { *; }
```